# Looping through validation messages and flash it using toastr

Tags: laravel

Please how can i loop through the  validation errors in laravel and flash it using *toastr.js*?

I tried something like this

```
var has_error = ({{ $errors->count() > 0 ? "true" : "false"}})

If(has_error){
     toastr.error(session::has('error'))
 }
```

But it's not working?